# Making userless requests in Foursquare API with easyFoursquare4Android library

Tags: android, foursquare, android-library

I'm making an Android app and am trying to use the [Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/). I started to use the Foursquare-recommended library, [easyFoursquare4Android](https://github.com/condesales/easyFoursquare4Android).

I registered my Foursquare app at https://foursquare.com/developers/apps. I Changed the `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` constant values in the easyFoursquare4Android library.

**How can I make userless requests such as getting nearby venues with the easyFoursquare4Android library?**

To get access to the API, you must call the `AccessTokenRequest` class, which tries to get an access token.

I found the [userless access section](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth#userless) in the Foursquare API Docs, which says that

"*To make a userless request, specify your consumer key's Client ID and Secret instead of an auth token in the request URL.*"

**Should I change the library since it doesn't look like it supports userless access?**

**Edit:**

I made an [issue](https://github.com/condesales/easyFoursquare4Android/issues/10) in the [easyFoursquare4Android library GitHub Repository](https://github.com/condesales/easyFoursquare4Android).

Comment: Client ID and Secret is authentication of developer, authToken is for user session, which means, it supports userless access. Even documentation states that you need to have clientID and Secret to access userless, so what is unclear about that?

Comment: @MarekSebera Nothing was unclear about the documentation. I know you need a client ID and secret for userless access and authToken for access with users. I'm asking about userless access with the easyFoursquare4Android library. Because it looks like it isn't possible. So I'm wondering if/how I should go about changing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library seems to rely on having an access token.

You possibly can override that behavior by editing the `hasAccessToken` method to return `true` in `EasyFoursquare` and `EasyFoursquareAsync`.

Comment: This didn't work. I get the error `Missing access credentials. See https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html for details.`, which makes sense because in a userless request such as `getVenuesNearby` the last parameter is the empty oath token.